# JavaScript Display Profit/Loss by Day

Tags: javascript, loops, html-lists

I am trying to display a profit or loss by day depending on whether there's a minus at the beginning of the string or not however something definitely doesn't work there...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Long list</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    Profit/Loss by Day
    <li>-$10</li>
    <li>$9</li>
    <li>$1</li>
    <li>$1</li>
    <li>$0</li>
    <li>$0</li>
    <li>$10</li>
    <li>-$7</li>
    <li>-$6</li>
    <li>-$9</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      let p = document.createElement('p');
      if (li[i][0] == '-') {
        p.innerHTML = `Day ${i+1}, I lost ${li[i].innerHTML}`;
        document.body.append(p);
      } else {
        p.innerHTML = `Day ${i+1}, I earned ${li[i].innerHTML}`;
        document.body.append(p);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add some comments on your code above to help us step through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.innerHTML` and `.indexOf` to check the position of `-` in the content of each list item:

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
     let p = document.createElement('p');
     if (li[i].innerHTML.indexOf('-') === 0) {
          p.innerHTML = `Day ${i+1}, I lost ${li[i].innerHTML}`;
          document.body.append(p);
     } else {
          p.innerHTML = `Day ${i+1}, I earned ${li[i].innerHTML}`;
          document.body.append(p);
     }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    Profit/Loss by Day
    <li>-$10</li>
    <li>$9</li>
    <li>$1</li>
    <li>$1</li>
    <li>$0</li>
    <li>$0</li>
    <li>$10</li>
    <li>-$7</li>
    <li>-$6</li>
    <li>-$9</li>
</ul>
```